# Java and layout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to use JPanels like containers from top to bottom just like DIV tags when creating a web page? If I use BorderLayout, I can have only two (NORTH and SOUTH)?

I want to place different `JButtons`, `JLabels` and `JTextFields` into each JPanels. This is the layout I'm trying to do:

> Container1 and it's content
>
> Container2 and it's content
>
> Container3 and it's content

Thanks for help.

EDIT: I added some part of my code beacuse I'm not sure I'm doing it right?

```
JPanel container1, container2, container3;
container1 = new JPanel();
container2 = new JPanel();
container3 = new JPanel();

container1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
container2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
container3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container3, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

// lägg till komponenter till containers
container1.add(button1);
container2.add(button2);
container3.add(button3);

// lägg till containers till fönster
frame.add(container1);
frame.add(container2);
frame.add(container3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) for this, when you set the number of columns to 1.
There is also the [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html), which should give this effect when you use the PAGE_LAYOUT or Y_AXIS orientations.

Here is some sample code for BoxLayout:

```
Container container = frame.getContentPane( );
frame.setLayout( new BoxLayout( container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS ) );

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel( );
panel1.add( new JButton( "Button #1" ) );
frame.add( panel1 );

JPanel panel2 = new JPanel( );
panel2.add( new JLabel("Label #1") );
frame.add( panel2 );
```

Note that the layout is set on the content pane of the frame, not on the frame directly. If you try to set the BoxLayout on the JFrame directly, you will get a "BoxLayout can't be shared" error.

Comment: BoxLayout sounds interesting, but would the JPanels cover all the space? If I use a background color, would it cover each space in a box?

Comment: I'm trying the code and have some problem! Should I not use this in the beginning: frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); and should I place the boxes like this: container1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); 
 container2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container2, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); I get so much space between. One button at top and another at the bottom!? Can I set some size for the boxes or the panels? Container1 and container2 is instances of JPanel

Comment: @3D-kreativ Please edit code into your question as an update.

Comment: @3D-kreativ There's no need to set the BorderLayout; I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm, Do I need to use the Container class and getContentPane? I thought this would not be necessary after version 5?

Comment: Thanks for the new code! Would each JPanel be a own box that I can fill with components? And if I create a new JPanel, it will be placed below the other? I have to make a brake and try the code later! Thanks!

Comment: New JPanels will be put under the JPanels already there. You can fill them as you see fit.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want the [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) layout manager. This particular layout manager makes vertically stacking components quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of elemts of a webpage is pretty much what `FlowLayout` does: show everything in a row (horizontal or vertical) and spill over into multiple rows if there is not enough space. If you want the arrangement to be fixed, use `BoxLayout`.

But note that if you nest layout managers, things can get a bit trickier. Here's an [article that explains it well](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/GUI/AWTLayoutMgr/shortcourse.html).